# Mysql2::Error: INSERT command denied to user 'username'@'host' for table 'schema_migrations': INSERT INTO `schema_migrations` (`version`) VALUES ('')

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, mysql2, sql-grant

I am trying to run `heroku run rake db:migrate -r staging` but I am getting this error.

```
Mysql2::Error: INSERT command denied to user 'username'@'host' for table 'schema_migrations': INSERT INTO `schema_migrations` (`version`) VALUES ('20170208234859')
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: INSERT command denied to user 'username'@'host' for table 'schema_migrations': INSERT INTO `schema_migrations` (`version`) VALUES ('20170208234859')/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:250:in `exec_insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:95:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:502:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:87:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:482:in `create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:125:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `block in save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:41:in `create!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1023:in `record_version_state_after_migrating'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:993:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1040:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: INSERT command denied to user 'username'@'host' for table 'schema_migrations': INSERT INTO `schema_migrations` (`version`) VALUES ('20170208234859')
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:250:in `exec_insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:95:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:502:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:87:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:482:in `create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:125:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `block in save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:41:in `create!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1023:in `record_version_state_after_migrating'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:993:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1040:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Mysql2::Error: INSERT command denied to user 'username'@'host' for table 'schema_migrations'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:250:in `exec_insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:95:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:502:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:87:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:482:in `create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:125:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `block in save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:41:in `create!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1023:in `record_version_state_after_migrating'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:993:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1040:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried many solutions but I can't resolve it yet.

I tried to grant all privileges to that user but it says that the access denied.

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'%' (using password: YES)

I also tried to show grants for this user but I get

```
mysql> show grants for 'username'@'host';
```

> ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user
>   'username' on host 'host'

When I run `show databases;` the (mysql) database does not exist only two databases exist (information_schema and my database)

I also tried answers on many questions on stackoverflow but nothing worked!

Comment: Is that the right command for migration ? I think, it should be like `heroku run rake db:migrate` .

Comment: You are right. I missed it while writing.

Comment: try. `GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO 'username'@'host';` replace `dbname` with our `db`

Comment: @MahmoudSayed did it work ? or you are still facing any problem ?

Comment: @Sajan No, it did not work.

Comment: @Sravan I also tried this before but it says access denied for this user.

Comment: When I run `show databases;` the (mysql) database does not exist only two databases exist (information_schema and my database), can this help to know what are the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was that my database has exceeded the maximum size given by cleardb for my plan. so my privileges were disabled.

[image]

I found similar problems here https://getsatisfaction.com/cleardb